# sort directories by last changed files inside using bash skript

Tags: bash, timestamp, directory

I have mount a windows share and want to ignore the timestamps of the lowermost folders inside.

I want to sort the directories by modification date of any file inside the directory or any subdirectory.

Is this possible? I only need the resulting directory list the first level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

I'll give you the outline of a solution:

1. Use a `for` loop to iterate over the top-level directories (in zsh, this is as simple as `*(/)`; in bash you may need something like `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d`.
2. For each directory,

   1. Call `find -type f` on the directory, using `-printf` to specify a format string that consists only of the modification time of the file found, followed by a newline.
   2. Pipe the result of `find` through `sort -n`.
   3. Pipe the result of `sort` through `tail -1`.
   4. Using something like `echo $(find | sort | tail) $dirname`, output the highest mtime found inside each directory, followed by the name of the directory.
3. Pipe the result of the above loop through `sort -t" " -k1,1 -n | cut -d" " -f2-`

This solution depends on the directory names not containing newlines.